# Parsing html (javascript) with python and beautifulsoup - corrupted characters

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

Like others, I'm trying to parsing some html.  It's coming from a TP Link switch.
the page seems to execute a bunch of java script which draws a table.  I seem to get back the test, of which in the javascript I can see two variables with a bunch of string data in it.

Here's the table:

```
Port    Status  Link Status TxGoodPkt   TxBadPkt   RxGoodPkt    RxBadPkt
Port 1  Enabled 100Full     498290637   0          131306261    210126
Port 2  Enabled Link Down   366673044   0           89192528    0
Port 3  Enabled 1000Full    311920199   0          866392497    0
```

When I view source in chrome I see (I'll skip some bits):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="gb2312" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
```

...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            var tmp_info = "1 5 498290637 0 131306261 210126 1 0 366673044 0 89192528 0 1 6 311920199 0 866392497 0 1 0 153684315 0 97002057 0 1 6 2538332183 0 2232309946 0 1 6 553132564 0 3773586010 0 1 5 73157327 0 24078837 1 1 5 77574150 0 221354757 4 1 5 68590536 0 663985 0 1 0 93665191 0 31213034 0 1 5 122289805 0 23777924 46 1 0 1206527230 0 1764357168 18 1 0 46099 0 37019 1 1 6 736786390 0 1105885411 0 1 0 32899021 0 60336561 0 1 5 426667546 0 1332459225 0 ";
                            var all_info = tmp_info.split(" ");
                            var index;
                            var port_middle_num = 16;
                            var tmp_info2;
                            var all_info2;
                            var port_id;
                            var state;
                            var link_status;
                            var tx_good;
                            var tx_bad;
                            var rx_good;
                            var rx_bad;

                            for (index = 0; index < port_middle_num; index++) {
                                port_id = index + 1;
                                port = "Port " + port_id;
                                state = state_info[Number(all_info[index * 6])];
                                link_status = link_info[Number(all_info[index * 6 + 1])];
                                tx_good = Number(all_info[index * 6 + 2]);
                                tx_bad = Number(all_info[index * 6 + 3]);
                                rx_good = Number(all_info[index * 6 + 4]);
                                rx_bad = Number(all_info[index * 6 + 5]);

                                document.write("<tr>");
                                document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + port);
                                document.write("</td>");
                                document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + state);
                                document.write("</td>");
                                document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + link_status);
                                document.write("</td>");
                                document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + tx_good);
                                document.write("</td>");
                                document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + tx_bad);
                                document.write("</td>");
                                document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + rx_good);
                                document.write("</td>");
                                document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + rx_bad);
                                document.write("</td>");
                                document.write("</tr>");

                            }

                            if (max_port_num > port_middle_num) {
                                var tmp_info2 = "1 0 3989143 0 893271 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 5 785410015 0 3466001895 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 333878647 0 461331415 0 1 6 1728705313 0 2383923975 0 1 6 3247361536 0 3009430904 1 ";
                                var all_info2 = tmp_info2.split(" ");

                                for (index = port_middle_num; index < max_port_num; index++) {
                                    port_id = index + 1;
                                    port = "Port " + port_id;
                                    state = state_info[Number(all_info2[(index - port_middle_num) * 6])];
                                    link_status = link_info[Number(all_info2[(index - port_middle_num) * 6 + 1])];
                                    tx_good = Number(all_info2[(index - port_middle_num) * 6 + 2]);
                                    tx_bad = Number(all_info2[(index - port_middle_num) * 6 + 3]);
                                    rx_good = Number(all_info2[(index - port_middle_num) * 6 + 4]);
                                    rx_bad = Number(all_info2[(index - port_middle_num) * 6 + 5]);

                                    document.write("<tr>");
                                    document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + port);
                                    document.write("</td>");
                                    document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + state);
                                    document.write("</td>");
                                    document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + link_status);
                                    document.write("</td>");
                                    document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + tx_good);
                                    document.write("</td>");
                                    document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + tx_bad);
                                    document.write("</td>");
                                    document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + rx_good);
                                    document.write("</td>");
                                    document.write("<td class=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + rx_bad);
                                    document.write("</td>");
                                    document.write("</tr>");
                                }
                            }

                        </script>
```

So there you can see the two variables tmp_info and tmp_info2.  I want these.

So when I parse with the following:

```
response = s.get('http://sg1024.lan/PortStatisticsRpm.htm')  # Your cookies and headers are automatically included

text = response.text.decode('gbk').encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,"lxml")
js_text = soup.find_all("script")[4].text
print js_text
```

I get:

```
var tmp_info = "1 5 498320672 0 131306757 210126 1 0 366673044 0 89192528 0 1 6 311987716 0 866437631 0 1 0 153684315 0 97002057 0 1 6 2539555814 0 2233951187 0 1 6 554951288 0 3774505382 0 1 5 73196797 0 24086933 1 1 5 77610569 0 221355051 4 1 5 68620483 0 664197 0 1 0 93665191 0 31213034 0 1 5 122320601 0 23785079 46 1 0 1206527230 0 1764357168 18 1 0 46099 0 37019 1 1 6 737390431 0 1106633759 0 1 0 32899021 0 60336561 0 1 5 429505364 0 1333919686 0 ";                                     if (max_var tmp_info2 = "1 0 3989143 0 893271 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 5 785815229 0 3466559497 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 333878647 0 461331415 0 1 6 1730171365 0 2386856}34 0 1 }or (inddocument.write("</tr>");s=\"TABLE_HEAD_BOTTOM\" align=center width=\"78px\">" + rx_bad);;us);
```

Pretty much all of it...but you can see in those last couple of lines it's been corrupted.

```
1 6 1728705313 0 2383923}75 0 1 }
```

should be

```
1 6 1728705313 0 2383923975 0 1 6 3247361536 0 3009430904 1
```

It seems to corrupt the 2383923975 , and misses the  6 3247361536 0 3009430904 1 (which is the last of the 24 ports).

Is there something to read it, or to read the page as the result table that should be written?

Comment: I think it will be difficult to find particular line because JavaScript doesn't contains html tags , so better find all script tag and then  find particular line by using regex (find line which contains var tmp_info)